# Gtk3 - Prevent TextView to make Window grow

Tags: layout, gtk, gtk3, scrollable

I am currently trying to create a small note app with GTK3. It's basically a `Window` that sticks on your desktop and is undecorated. Currently it contains a `Button` and a `TextView` which reside in a `ListBox`. However as soon as the `TextView` has more rows of text than space for rows of text, the  `TextView` and the `Window` will grow. The `Window` will actually grow bigger than the screen is.

What I have tried:

- `window.SetResizable(false)`
- using `SetVExpand(false)` on the `Window` and the `ListBox`
- Wrapping the TextView in a `Layout`, which the documentation claims is a scrollable container (I probably misunderstood)

Comment: FYI, a scrollable container can be placed into a ScrolledWindow directly. A non-scrollable container needs to have a ViewPort in between the container and the ScrolledWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply used `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`.

```
var hAdjustment, vAdjustment *gtk.Adjustment
textViewScrollPane, _ := gtk.ScrolledWindowNew(hAdjustment, vAdjustment)

textView, _ := gtk.TextViewNew()

textViewScrollPane.Add(textView)
```

The example is `Go`, but it doesn't really matter.